# Something wrong with the SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've got an error with following SQL query

```
WITH `goal_owners` AS (SELECT `goals_owners`.`goal_id` AS goal_id FROM `users`) SELECT `goals`.* FROM `goals` WHERE `goals`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

the error says

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`goal_owners` AS (SELECT `goals_owners`.`goal_id` AS goal_id FROM `users`) SELEC' at line 1: WITH `goal_owners` AS (SELECT `goals_owners`.`goal_id` AS goal_id FROM `users`) SELECT  `goals`.* FROM `goals` WHERE `goals`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY `goals`.`id` ASC LIMIT ?
from /Users/hao/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:115:in `prepare'
Caused by Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`goal_owners` AS (SELECT `goals_owners`.`goal_id` AS goal_id FROM `users`) SELEC' at line 1
from /Users/hao/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:115:in `prepare'
```

mysql version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: Please update with the code that generates the query.

Comment: The SQL code in your question isn't using the CTE, is that the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for CTE (Common Table Expressions) prior to MySQL 8.

You can update your query, or to upgrade the MySQL version your application is running with.